# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am getting this:

```
GET http://locaohost:3001/api/v1/restaurants/ net:: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

when I load from another computer in the local network.

How can I overcome this issue? It only comes when I try to run the react app from the remote computer in the same network.

Comment: You need to give `IP` of the remote computer in the local network and not `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the IP address instead of localhost like the following:

`http://192.168.0.115:3001/api/v1/restaurants/`

To find your IP address, in windows OS you should open CMD and run `ipconfig` command and in macOS, you should open Terminal and run `ifconfig` command